# Acumatica. Get ItemClass Attributes on Sales Order dialog box

Tags: attributes, acumatica

I’m trying to get the Attributes per ItemClassId to place them on a grid in the look up dialog box (Sales Order Entry).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wFbB.png)

I’m using the CSAttributeGroupList method:

```
public PXFilter<SOSiteStatusFilter> ItemSearchClass;
{
[PXViewName("Attributes")]

CSAttributeGroupList<INItemClass, SOSiteStatusFilter> Attributes;
public PXFilter<SOSiteStatusFilter> ItemSearchClass;

[PXViewName("Attributes")]

CSAttributeGroupList<INItemClass, SOSiteStatusFilter> Attributes;
}
```

I can't find the proper way to bring the attributes from each ItemClassID.

I have tryed:

```
public CSAttributeGroupList<INItemClass, SOSiteStatusFilter> Attributes;
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you trying to just list the attributes on the class, or show the attribute values of the current selected row on the grid?

Comment: Hey KRichardson! I'm trying to get the attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

I would first put SyncPosition=True on the grid to the right, to ensure that the current inventory item is selected. From there, you would want to use the code that is found in InventoryItemMaintBase:

```
    public CRAttributeList<InventoryItem> Answers;
```

This would pull the current inventory item's attributes, and should automatically link to the items answers. You may need to mess with getting the grid on the right to refresh after the row is selected for the inventory item, if it does not do it automatically.